# Need help for text height in iText or iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a PDF form template which 20% of its size dedicated to header (head section) on the top and the remaining 80% of its height dedicated to a table filling with texts (body section), i want to extend the text to the next page body section if text does not fit to the previous body section page
Whats the best way to do that ?

Comment: How do you write the text? Using a Content Byte or Chunks/Phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out how to solve this problem I should create a table with 1 rows at the top and set it as a HeaderRow then it will be repeated in every new page.